# Inputing fixed column data into SAS using external description file

Tags: sas

I'm attempting to input Nielsen Claritas data into SAS which is in fixed column format. It looks like there are just shy of 1000 variables. There are descriptive text files included with each .dat file. I'm thinking there is probably a way to utilize this descriptive txt file to specify input lengths, names, formats et cetera. Can anyone give me an idea on the simplest way to do this?

After a few hours of searching I cannot find any canned functions and my best guess involves reformatting the descriptive txt file with a do loop. I also have access to and experience with R, Stata and SAS Enterprise guide if any of these programs will provide a simpler method.

This is an example of the descriptive file:

```
RECORD LAYOUT: 2013.1 Pop-Facts Premier (2000) Data   (ZIP Codes Level)

POSITION     TYPE SIZE  CONTENTS

    1-    2   A    2    Record Type
    3-    4   A    2    FIPS State Code
    5-    7   A    3    FIPS County Code
    8-   12   A    5    FIPS Minor Civil Division (MCD) Code
   13-   18   A    6    Census Tract Code
   19-   19   A    1    Census Block Group (BG) Code
   20-   23   A    4    Metropolitan Statistical Area or New England County     
                        Metro Area (MSA/NECMA) Code                             
   24-   28   A    5    Core Based Statistical Area Code
   29-   33   A    5    ZipCode
   34-   38   A    5    FIPS Place Code
   39-   41   A    3    Designated Marketing Area (DMA) Code
   42-   43   A    2    Congressional District Code
   44-   63   A   20    State Name
   64-   95   A   32    County Name
   96-  145   A   50    Core Based Statistical Area Name
  146-  177   A   32    Geography Name
  178-  192   A   15    Geography Code (Concatenated Geography Code)
  193-  202   F 10.6    Latitude
  203-  213   F 11.6    Longitude

                        2000 Population by Single Race and Sex

  337-  345   I    9    2000 Population, White Alone
  346-  354   I    9    2000 Population, White Alone, Male
  355-  363   I    9    2000 Population, White Alone, Female
  364-  372   I    9    2000 Population, Black/African American Alone
  373-  381   I    9    2000 Population, Black/African American Alone, Male
  382-  390   I    9    2000 Population, Black/African American Alone, Female
  391-  399   I    9    2000 Population, American Indian/Alaskan Native Alone
  400-  408   I    9    2000 Population, American Indian/Alaskan Native Alone,  
                        Male                                                    
  409-  417   I    9    2000 Population, American Indian/Alaskan Native Alone,  
                        Female                                                  
  418-  426   I    9    2000 Population, Asian Alone
  427-  435   I    9    2000 Population, Asian Alone, Male
  436-  444   I    9    2000 Population, Asian Alone, Female
  445-  453   I    9    2000 Population, Native Hawaiian/Pacific Islander Alone
  454-  462   I    9    2000 Population, Native Hawaiian/Pacific Islander       
                        Alone, Male                                             
  463-  471   I    9    2000 Population, Native Hawaiian/Pacific Islander       
                        Alone, Female                                           
  472-  480   I    9    2000 Population, Some Other Race Alone
  481-  489   I    9    2000 Population, Some Other Race Alone, Male
  490-  498   I    9    2000 Population, Some Other Race Alone, Female
  499-  507   I    9    2000 Population, Two or More Races
  508-  516   I    9    2000 Population, Two or More Races, Male
  517-  525   I    9    2000 Population, Two or More Races, Female
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the descriptive text file (and maybe some of your own code attempting to tackle the problem)? You probably just need a simple macro.

Comment: Yes, thank you John. I've edited the original post to include an example of the description file. I've not written any code yet as it seemed inefficient to reinvent the wheel if there was a preexisting canned function.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you'll need to create a dataset that looks like:

```
colname | start | length | informat
```

where informat at least contains ($ or nothing), and possibly some information about if it is a date/etc.

Then you can write a macro, something like this:

```
%macro readincol(col,start,len,informat);
@&start. &col. &informat.$len..
%mend readincol;
```

And you then read in the first dataset's rows into a macro variable like so:

```
proc sql;
  select cats('%readincol(',colname,',',start,',',length,',',informat,')') into :inputst
    separated by ' ' from layout_dset;
quit;
```

Now you have your constructed input statement and can use it in a datastep:

```
data want;
infile "myfile.txt" lrecl=32767;
input
&inputst.
;
run;
```

You also might be able to assign formats/etc., depending on the data, the layout, and your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it in one DATA step (after creating layout dataset like in Joe's answer) using CALL EXECUTE:

```
data _null_;
call execute(
    "data want;
        infile 'myfile.txt' lrecl=32767;
        input");
do until(eof);
   set layout_dset end=eof;
   call execute(cats("@",start)||colname||" "||cats(informat,length,"."));
end;
call execute(";run;");
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to generate SAS code to read that "descriptive text" file and create a SAS data set. There really isn't a good way to tell you how to do this; it's easier to just show you an example program using the data you provided.

The following should give you a good start. Notice that your source description does not provide and column names, so I just used a range (VARnnn).  You will need to modify this program for each file you want to process,  The input is a text file exactly as you have shown; the output is another text file containing the SAS program.

Also note that you did not provide an example of reading any DATE or DATETIME values; if those exist somewhere, you will need to make appropriate changes.

Here is the code (tested using the example you provided):

```
data inputs(keep=input_stmt)
     vars(keep=attrib dslabel);

   length dslabel $60 input_stmt attrib $200;
   retain varnum 0 dslabel;
   infile 'c:\temp\table1.txt' truncover;

   input @;
   if _infile_ =: 'RECORD LAYOUT:' then do;
      dslabel = substr(_infile_,16);
      input ///; /* skip next 3 lines */
      delete;
      end;

   input @1 START $5. @7 END 5. @15 TYPE $1. @17 SIZE $4. @25 LABEL $80.;
   if START ne ' '; /* ignore blank and non-data lines */
   varnum + 1; /* Variable counter */

   varname = 'VAR' || put(varnum,z3.);
   select(TYPE);
      when( 'A' ) infmt = '$' || trim(SIZE) || '.'; 
      when( 'F' ) infmt = SIZE; 
      when( 'I' ) infmt = trim(SIZE) || '.';
      otherwise   infmt = '$' || trim(SIZE) || '.'; /* Read as character */
      end;

   attrib = 'ATTRIB ' || trim(varname) || ' INFORMAT='
         || trim(infmt) || " LABEL='" || trim(label) || "';";

   input_stmt = '@' || trim(start) || ' ' || trim(varname) || ' ' 
               || trim(infmt);
run;

data _null_;
   file 'c:\temp\read_table1.sas' new;
   set vars;
   if _n_ = 1 then
      put "data table1(label='" dslabel "');"; 
   put attrib;
run;

data _null_;
   file 'c:\temp\read_table1.sas' mod;
   set inputs end=eof;
   if _n_ = 1 then
      put 'input'; 
   put @5 input_stmt;
   if eof then put ';' / 'run;';
run;
```

Answer (score -2):

Yeah I have had to deal with that same data... It's not fun. What I have been doing is copying all the data from the text files and pasting them into Excel - cell A4 (using text to columns - fixed width text columns). Then I have being using a syntax in Excel to fix the darn formating...

=IF(A4<> "", IF(B5="", CONCATENATE(C4&" "&C5), C4), "")

Then I have been sorting the data to eliminate the spaces. Any idea how to clean this data or import it to SQL as is would be helpful.